# Is there any relation between continuity and weak lower semicontinuity?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let a normed space $S$ be given.

Then we say a function $f$ is continuous on $S$ if $s_n\to s$, we have $f(s_n)\to f(s)$, and we say $f$ is weakly $l.s.c.$ if $s_n\to s$ weakly in $S$, then $\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(s_n)\geq f(s)$.

My question: is there any relation between those two definition? i.e., continuity implies weak $l.s.c.$, or v.v., or neither? Any counterexamples?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Continuity implies lower semicontinuity, but not the other way around.

The proof of continuity implying lower semicontinuity is pretty straightforward. By continuity, if $s_n \rightarrow s$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(s_n) = f(s)$. Since the limit exists, clearly the limit inferior coincides with the limit, so that $\lim \inf_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(s_n) = f(s)$, which implies the definition of $l.s.c.$

To show that lower semicontinuity does not imply continuity, consider the piecewise function $f : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x) = x^2$ for $x < 0$ and $f(x) = x + 1$ for $x \ge 0$. I've attached an image below. This function is continuous everywhere except at the point $0$. Since continuity implies $l.s.c.$, to show this function is $l.s.c.,$ we only need to show that the $l.s.c.$ condition holds at $0$, and this can be easily verified. For any sequence $s_n \rightarrow 0$, it is clear that $\lim \inf_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(s_n) \ge f(0) = -1.$

[image]

Comment: I got a bit confused. If you want to show $f$ is $l.s.c.$, then you only have a sequence $s_n$ which is weakly convergence to $s$, but not strongly convergence to $s$, and hence you can not apply the definition of strong convergence which require $s_n\to s$.

Comment: My bad, I only write weakly in the statement but forgot to add the word "weak" in the title. corrected

Answer (score 0):

There is the nice implication: convexity + continuity implies weakly lower semicontinuity.

Continuity alone is not sufficient, consider, e.g., $f(x) = -\|x\|$.

Convexity alone is also not sufficient: take a linear and discontinuous functional $f$.